# Define forward declared C-struct as C++-struct

Tags: c++, c, forward-declaration

Is it legal to forward-declare a `struct` as a C-`struct`

```
// api.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    typedef struct handle_tag handle_t;

    handle_t *construct();
    void destruct(handle_t *h);

    void func(handle_t *h);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

and subsequently define it as a C++-`struct`, i.e. as a non-POD type?

```
// api.cpp
struct handle_tag {
    void func();
    std::string member;
};

void func(handle_t *h) {
    h->func();
}
```

The general intention is to get via a C interface an externally accessible opaque type `handle_t` which is internally implemented as an C++ data type.

Comment: Incidentally, PODness is unrelated to C vs. C++ linkage. C++ names are mangled regardless of whether they are PODs.

Comment: @KonradRudolph That struct is not POD

Comment: @BЈовић Well yeah, nobody claimed it to be, no?

Comment: @ChristianRau Ok, was wondering why he mentioned PODs

Comment: Naming quibble: a "handle" is something that gives you an indirect way to refer to something, similar to a pointer. Giving your heavy struct the name "handle_t" and then asking the user to use pointers to it doesn't make sense. Instead, give the struct some other name and typedef "handle_t" to be a pointer to it. Then use that type directly instead of pointers.

Comment: @Sebastian: I don't understand. In any case I have to forward-declare a struct in C, haven't I? Ok, I could've called it `handle_impl` instead of `handle_tag` -- but nevertheless I have to forward-declare it inside the header.

Comment: You do. My point is that the type `handle_t*` looks extremely unnatural to me, and I would probably use plain `handle_t` constantly and unconsciously and then be annoyed when it doesn't compile. Compare the `HANDLE` and similar types in the Windows API.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that will work fine as long as the C code never needs to see "inside" the `handle_tag` structure, and the appropriate C++ construction/destruction is performed by the C++ code (which I preseume the `construct` and `destruct` are for).

All that the C code needs is a pointer to some datastructure - it won't know what the contents is, so the content can be anything you like it to to be, including constructor/destructor reliant data.

Edit: 
I should point out that this, or methods similar to it (e.g. using a `void *` to record the address of an object for the C portion to `hold`), is a fairly common way to interface C-code to C++ functionality.

Edit2: 
It is critical that the C++ code called doesn't "leak" exceptions into the C code. That is undefined behaviour, and very much liable to cause crashes, or worse, "weird things" that don't crash... So unless the code is guaranteed to not cause exceptions (and for example `std::string` is liable to throw `bad_alloc` in case of low memory), it is required to use a `try/catch` block inside code like `construct` anf `func` in the C++ side.

Comment: You sure that works? Will the object file for `api.cpp` export a non-mangled name for `handle_tag`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: usually only variables and functions manifest themselves as exported names, just a type itself doesnt have any mangled name.

Comment: as long as you use the exported typedef only as a pointer, you will have no problem doing this. The C doesnt need to know the size of the struct to know the size of a pointer to that struct.

Comment: the names for `struct`, `class` and `union` are not "exported". They are used by the compiler during compilation - and used for name-mangling, but as long as the C callable functions are wrapped with `extern "C"`, that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Sure they are. Since when does the C ABI support templates and namespaces? But I agree, there’s no reason to mangle a non-template type in the global namespace. But is this universally guaranteed?

Comment: @KonradRudolph The names of structures, etc, are the same during compilation. Name mangling only happens on the symbols resolved by the linker. And as I said, that should be fine as long as `extern "C"` is used to indicate that we don't want name mangling on the functions that are called. I just thought of another point that I will edit into the answer tho'.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Since the standard doesn't talk about any name mangling requirements, nothing in that regard is guaranteed. But even for templates, the type names you find in mangled names are usually only part of variable and function names (unless you talk about debugging symbols)

Comment: @PlasmaHH If I look at the exported names of a CU via `nm` I do see the mangled type names there, and no unmangled ones: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ab1933a6473a489c6ad5a1ff421f01b8-133ed68914a1f45e29f55969a986bc3f

Comment: @KonradRudolph if you run that through c++filt I think you'll find that at no point is a symbol that is just the name of a struct is exported. You can even try the reverse if you're not convinced a pure c program with a struct and run nm on that. The struct itself will not appear.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Just exactly as I said, they are part of a variable or function name.

Comment: @Logan Hmm, I’ve just tried demangling them using the [GCC API](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a01696.html) and I get only error messages so I’ll take your word for it. I can’t demangle the names manually but it looks indeed as if the last part of the names codes for argument types or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Won't work quite as is, but the concept's ok.  When the functions are *defined*, you also need to make sure the names aren't mangled so that the C code can find them.  That means `#include "api.h"` should be added atop your api.cpp file.